# how is angular velocity calculated from odometry?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a hall effect sensor on one of my robot wheels (4 wheels in total). I use it to calculate the linear velocity for geometry_msgs/Twist message. How does one calculate angular velocity from just odometry? Are hall sensors even good enough, seeing as everyone else use wheel encoders?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298529/how-is-angular-velocity-calculated-from-odometry?/) by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2018-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably have differential kinematics? Am I right? Angular velocity would than be calculated from a speed difference between left and right wheels and distance between them. An example for this you can find in [neo_driver](https://github.com/neobotix/neo_driver/blob/indigo_dev/neo_platformctrl_diff/common/src/DiffDrive2WKinematics.cpp) package. See function `execForwKin`. For theory make some Internet search on differential kinematics. There are plenty of presentations from university courses.

EDIT:
After clarifying the kinematics which is skid-steering one should look at [diff_drive_controller](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/tree/a9e650737d6d04d8a768c84a48763bdbc5e05800/diff_drive_controller) which also enables skid-stearing. For start see this [file](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/a9e650737d6d04d8a768c84a48763bdbc5e05800/diff_drive_controller/test/skidsteerbot.cpp).

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-25**:
Sadly no, I have a small RC car where the wheels rotate at more or less the same speed, no differential. Is odometry achievable with such vehicle?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-25**:
@Hypomania: so your platform uses Ackermann kinematics?

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-25**:
I had to look it up, I think that's what it is. Imagine a cheap RC car without any differentials, would you call that Ackermann kinematics?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-25**:
If you have 4 wheels of which two are fixed and two are used for "car-like steering", then yes, it would be considered Ackermann.

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-07-25**:
The ackermann kinematics is also well known and there is plenty of stuff in Internet. Unfortunately I do not know any ROS driver for it where you can directly look it up

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-25**:
@Hypomania: you can probably take a look at [easymov/ackermann_controller](https://github.com/easymov/ackermann_controller) (and the related packages). That could probably save you quite some time and effort. See also [wiki/Ackermann Group](http://wiki.ros.org/Ackermann%20Group).

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-25**:
@gvdhoorn, okay, I did more research, my RC car is a 4 wheel drive car with a center transfer box and center steer. There is no Ackermann geometry on it, my colleague said it "relies on torque bias and backlash from the drive system" to improve steering efficiency. It can do a perfect circle.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-25**:
Ah, that sounds more like skid-steering then.

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-25**:
@gvdhoorn, so it safe to assume that the front wheels are turning at different speeds aka having a differential effect? Basically, what's the most suitable driver package for such vehicle?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-25**:
I don't know whether that is safe to assume. I'm not an expert.

There are some pkgs that support skid steering (as it's quite common: many clearpath robots use it fi). See [wiki/diff_drive_controller - Skid steer](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller#Skid_steer) for one.

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-07-25**:
I also edited my answer accordingly.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-25**:
@destogl: not sure `skidsteerbot.cpp` is the best place to start here. It's top-level and requires some digging to get to the interesting bits.

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-25**:
@gvdhoorn, @destogl, thank you for your advices, I will start looking into the packages you have suggested!

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-07-25**:
@Hypomania when you find better example please tell us so I can update my answer for other people.

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-25**:
@destogl, will do my friend

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-25**:
@gvdhoorn, last question, how many two wheel encoders do I need in my scenario?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-25**:
I don't understand your question.

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-26**:
@gvdhoorn, sorry, I was meant to ask how many wheel encoders would I need (in my situation), two or one?

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-07-26**:
For each wheel one. Maybe you can come with only 2, one on each side. It depends on the mechanical quality of your robot

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-26**:
@destogl, wouldn't the back left wheel spin at the same speed as front left wheel (same thing for the right side)?

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-07-26**:
That is what i meant about 2 encoders. But if mechanics is crappy strange things can happen :) (just my experience working with crappy mechanics)

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-27**:
@destogl, thank you for your help, really appreciate it!